# How to compress XML (CLOB data) in Oracle?

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, compression, clob

Oracle 11.2.0.4

I trying to compress XML (XMLTYPE dbfield) via java class methods href here: 
[LOB compression](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:12980645053487)

The class was successfully compiled.

```
SELECT  OBJECT_NAME,
        OBJECT_TYPE
    FROM DBA_OBJECTS
    WHERE OBJECT_NAME LIKE '%LobCompress%'
    ORDER BY 1;
-------------------

OBJECT_NAME OBJECT_TYPE
LobCompressor   JAVA CLASS
LobCompressor   JAVA SOURCE
```

but error appears in RT when calling this methods:

```
DECLARE
dr MY_USER.ORDER_CONFIG%ROWTYPE;
bZipped BLOB;
...
SELECT * INTO dr
            FROM MY_USER.ORDER_CONFIG oc
            WHERE oc.ORDER_NO = '3751017';


bZipped := MY_USER.PKG_COMPRESSOR.CLOB_COMPRESS(dr.CONFIG_XML);
```

> ORA-29540: class LobCompressor does not exist ORA-06512: at
>   "MY_USER.PKG_COMPRESSOR", line 10 ORA-06512: at
>   "MY_USER.PKG_COMPRESSOR", line 39 ORA-06512: at line 13

dr.CONFIG_XML has not empty / not null value

What i need to do for correct script work?

PS this is my first time i am trying to use java class in pl sql

Comment: Does your user has a privilege for LobCompres class. Check this class in `all_dba_objects`. 
Add also part of code with java publication in plsql. `PKG_COMPRESSOR.CLOB_COMPRESS`. Or follow advice given by @Wernfried Domscheit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think nowadays the most useful way for compressing XMLTYPE and/or LOB is to make compression on tablespace level.

When you create columns of XMLTYPE or any LOB you have to specify [LOB_storage_clause](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#i2218765). Compress entire tablespace where such objects are stored.

See also [XMLType_storage](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#sthref5754):

> In earlier releases, binary XML data is stored by default in a
>   BasicFiles LOB. Beginning with Oracle Database 11g Release 2
>   (11.2.0.2), if the COMPATIBLE initialization parameter is 11.2 or
>   higher and you do not specify BASICFILE or SECUREFILE, then binary XML
>   data is stored in a SecureFiles LOB whenever possible. If SecureFiles
>   LOB storage is not possible then the binary XML data is stored in a
>   BasicFiles LOB.

SecureFiles provide compression, deduplication, and encryption.

Comment: Hi what about CLOB column data. Is that automatically compressed. I am on 12 c. Please let me know if there is a way through which we can find if data is compressed.

Comment: @tarun_tenniso, see [LOB_compression_clause](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#sthref5740)